# Can't I use column alias in JPAQuery `having` method?

Tags: querydsl

I am trying to create some dashboard service using `springboot` and `spring-data-jpa` with `querydsl`.

And I should align datas using two key(no, updatedAt) in other tables, so I try to make this query using `querydsl`.

```
select
    f.no,
    a.no,
    a.updated_at,
    ((coalesce(unix_timestamp(updated_at), 0) * 1000000000) + f.no) as align
from
    follow f 
inner join
    author a 
        on (
            f.author_no=a.no
        ) 
where
    f.id="testid"
group by f.no
having align < 1659494328001399789
order by
    align desc
limit 10;
```

There is my code using `querydsl`

```
String someId = "testId";

NumberExpression<Long> alignExpression = Expressions.numberTemplate(
    Long.class,
    "coalesce(UNIX_TIMESTAMP({0}), 0)", authorEntity.updatedAt
    )
    .multiply(1000000000)
    .add(authorEntity.no);

NumberPath<Long> path = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "compoundSortKey");

return jpaQueryFactory.select(
    new QAuthorFollowProjection(
        followEntity,
        authorEntity,
        alignExpression.as(path))
    )
    .from(authorEntity)
    .innerJoin(authorEntity).on(followEntity.authorNo.eq(authorEntity.no))
    .where(
        authorEntity.id.eq(someId)
    )
    .groupBy(followEntity.no)
    .having(path.lt(1659494328001399789L))
    .orderBy(
        path.desc()
    )
    .limit(size)
    .fetch();
```

BUT in logs, here is `created sql query` and error message.

```
select
    followenti0_.no as col_0_0_,
    authorenti1_.no as col_1_0_,
    coalesce(unix_timestamp(authorenti1_.last_post_updated_at),
    0)*?+followenti0_.no as col_2_0_,
    followenti0_.no as no1_3_0_,
    authorenti1_.no as no1_0_1_,
    followenti0_.author_no as author_n5_3_0_,
    followenti0_.id_no as id_no6_3_0_,
    authorenti1_.updated_at as updated_3_0_1_
from
    follow followenti0_ 
inner join
    author authorenti1_ 
       on (
            followenti0_.author_no=authorenti1_.no
       ) 
where
    followenti0_.id_no=? 
group by
    col_2_0_ 
having
    compoundSortKey<? 
order by
    col_2_0_ desc limit ?



Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'compoundSortKey' in 'having clause'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 118 common frames omitted
```

Variable name didn't change from **compoundSortKey** to **col_2_0_** in only `having clause`, not in `group by` and `order by`.

I don't know why it didn't change.

Am I make something wrong code?

If not, `querydsl` don't support column alias in `having` method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Querydsl will render aliases in the having clause. However, in the JPQL query and not the SQL query. JPA officially doesn't support aliases in the having clause. So that means that your ORM might not allow the query. For Hibernate specifically I implemented handling for that myself. A feature that was introduced with Hibernate 5.4.10: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9301. For other JPA implementations unfortunately you're out of luck.